# Is there a relation which is neither symmetric nor antisymmetric?

Tags: relations

I've proved that there are relations which are both symmetric and antisymmetric ($\forall a \forall b (aRb \rightarrow (a=b))$) and now I'm trying to prove that there are relations which are neither symmetric nor antisymmetric. I got stuck! Any ideas?

Comment: Think of a set that contains a couple of elements. Come up with a relation on that set such that for some pairs of elements (x, y), $x R y$ and $\lnot (y R x)$; but for other pairs of elements (x, y), $x R y$ and $y R x$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If **every** pair satisfies $aRb\rightarrow bRa$ then the relation is symmetric. If there is *at least one* pair which fails to satisfy that then it is not symmetric.

Similarly if there is *at least* one pair which has $(aRb\rightarrow bRa)\land a\neq b$ then antisymmetry is also not satisfied.

We can therefore take the following relation: $\{a,b,c\}$ would be our universe and $R=\{\langle a,b\rangle,\langle b,a\rangle,\langle a,c\rangle\}$.

The fact that $aRc\land\lnot cRa$ shows that the relation is *not* symmetric, but $a\neq b$ and both $aRb$ and $bRa$ hold.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a relation on a set $A$ is just a subset of $A\times A$. So, you can just pick a convenient subset $R \subset A \times A$ so that only for SOME elements $a,b$ of $A$(I.e. not all), both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are in $R$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $aRb$ and $bRc$ and $cRb$.  And that's as far as $R$ goes.  It's not symmetric since $(\text{not }bRa)$ and it's not antisymmetric since both $bRc$ and $cRb$.

Answer (score 1):

To say that a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is not symmetric is equivalent to saying that there exist elements $a$ and $b$ in $A$ such that $aRb$ and $\require{cancel}b\cancel{R}a$. To say that a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is not antisymmetric is equivalent to saying that there exists an element $a\in A$ and an element $b\in A$ such that $a\ne b$, $aRb$, and $bRa.$ Consider the relation $R = \{\ (a,b)\ |\ ab^{2}\ \gt\ 0\}$ on the set of all integers $\mathbb Z$. Since $2\cdot (-1)^{2} = 2\gt 0$, the ordered pair $(2, -1)\in R$. However, since $(-1)\cdot 2^{2} = -4 \not\gt 0$, $(-1, 2)\not\in R$, thus $R$ is not symmetric. Similarly, we can show that $R$ is not antisymmetric by noting that the inequality $ab^{2}\gt0$ will hold for any two positive integers $a$ and $b$.  Thus, there exists a distinct pair of integers $a$ and $b$ such that $aRb$ and $bRa$. Hence, $R$ cannot be antisymmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be many relations which are neither symmetric nor antisymmetric . For example; Consider a set $S={a,b,c,d}$ and the relation on $S$ given by
      $$R=\{(a,b), (b,a), (c,d)\}.$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to use Mathjax to nicely format your mathematics on this site.